# post_tag taxonomy with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I'm looking all over google but doesn't find the way to do it.

i've declared a custom post type (let's say 'job') with a custom hierarchical taxonomy ('activities').

I would also like to assign "normal" tags to my custom post type (if i have a tag 'full employment' for my classic posts, i want to assign to my job posts also).

how can i achieve that ?

i managed to have a custom taxonomy on several post types, but i don't know how to target post_tag and add him a post type.

for example :

```
register_taxonomy( 'seasons', array('job', 'post'), $args );
```

make seasons appear on classic posts and also on job posts. I would like to have 'tags' available for my job posts.

am i clear ?

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enabling tags in a custom post type is quite simple. You need to use `'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')` while calling `register_post_type()`.

For Example:

```
register_post_type('movies',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name'          =>  'Movies',
                'singular_name' =>  'Movie',
                'menu_name'     =>  'MOVIES',
                'all_items'     =>  'All Movies',
                'add_new'       =>  'Add A Movie',
                'add_new_item'  =>  'Add New Movie'
                ),
            'public'    => true,
            'supports'  => array(
                            'title',
                            'post-formats',
                            ),
            'show_in_admin_bar' =>  true,
            'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
            )
        );
```

Look for the last `taxanomies => array('post_tag')` in code. This is how you enable tags in a custom post type.

Comment: great it works ! thank you. 
i haven't guessed post type options could change admin interface...